# How to replace values in as string which is in Json format

Tags: c#

I need to replace values of date and format field in below string. Can you please help in this regard.
Example: Input

```json
{
    "date": dummydate,    
    "format": dummyformat,
    "name": "kumar"
}
```

Output

```
{
    "date": ISODate(2022-07-17T21:45:50.955Z),
    "format":  NumberLong(100307006),
    "name": "kumar"
}
```

Note: data value and format value is not a string.

Comment: json-String -> c# object -> replace -> json-String

Comment: That's the second time today you asked a question about JSON while showcasing non-valid JSON

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In C#, you can use the `String.Replace()` method to replace a specific value in a string. For example, the following code would replace the `dummydate` and `dummyformat` values in the string with the specified values:

```cs
string input = "{ \"date\": dummydate, \"format\": dummyformat, \"name\": \"kumar\" }";
string output = input.Replace("dummydate", "ISODate(2022-07-17T21:45:50.955Z)").Replace("dummyformat", "NumberLong(100307006)");

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output:

```
{ "date": ISODate(2022-07-17T21:45:50.955Z), "format": NumberLong(100307006), "name": "kumar" }
```

Comment: And what if the input's date format is `2020/19/09`? Or, literally anything other than `dummydate`?

Comment: using string operations on JSON is generally a _bad_ idea and shouldn't be done.